# CSS3 - label and checkbox

Tags: html, css

[image]

HTML

```
 <div class="select">
      <div>
        <label for="kitty" class="kitty-label kitty-label-1 l-center">
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cats" value="1">
        <label>Kitty One</label>
      </div>
      <div class="cly-pam" style="width:50%; float: left">
        <label for="kitty" class="kitty-label kitty-label-2 l-center">
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cats" value="2">
        <label>Kitty Two</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
```

css

```
label{
  cursor: pointer;
}

    .kitty-label{
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      &:hover,
      &:focus,
      &:active{
        border-radius: 6px solid #fff;
      }
    }
    .kitty-label-1{
          display: inline-block;
          background: url(../img/kitty1.png) no-repeat 0 0;
          height: 142px;
          width: 142px;
    }

    .kitty-label-2{
          display: inline-block;
          background: url(../img/kitty2.png) no-repeat 0 0;
          height: 144px;
          width: 144px;
    }

    .select input[type="checkbox"]{
      display: none;
      &:checked + label:before{
        background: url(../img/tick.png) no-repeat;
      }
    }
```

The labels would have background image but the issue is that when focus, active or hover, the border-radius does not appear behind the images. Also the kitty images do not have border-radius edges. Wonder if should have image in circle shape or css3 can do that?

Also checkbox seems not to show the tick or anything. Tried to click on label (as in kitty image), tick doesn't appear?

Not sure where I might go wrong. Help will be very much appreciated.

**Updated**

```
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="designer" id="designer">
    <label for="designer" id="designer" class="inline-block testsign" style="background: url(../img/face.png) no-repeat center;">
    </label></div>
```

CSS

```
.testsign{
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  &:hover,
  &:focus,
  &:active{
     border: 15px solid #f3f3f3;

  }
}

// [type="radio"]:not(:checked),
// [type="radio"]:checked {
//   visibility: hidden;

input[type="radio"]:checked + label:after {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    background: #f0f1f1 url(../img/tick.png) no-repeat center center;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 10px solid #fff;
}
```

Attempted the example from @misterMan

Couldn't get the label:after to be positioned at the right bottom - tried top and left to position the tick circle, but the problem is that when checked, it will appear in the position which followed top and left. So if check extra element or image, tick circle will appear in the same place which is not right. Removed the top and left. There is no way to have tick circle positioned in right bottom appearing in each label whenever radio is checked?

Also another problem is that when border radius on the label is hovered on background image, and if checked radio, the tick circle (label:after) will appear, the tick circle will be "jumpy" whenever hovered on label. How to stop the jump? I tried to add absolute center and position relative but the labels will be out of the container.

Help or insight will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I love this type of stuff so I made this for you, if you are still looking for a solution. I have added the images with `<img>` as they are not decoration, they are primary content :)

It's nice and simple, and I think does what you want. Let me know!

**Updated**

[Have an updated fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/Cn7SC/5/)

HTML

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" id="pic1" />
    <label for="pic1">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" />
    </label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="pic2" />
    <label for="pic2">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" />
    </label>
</form>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}
label {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 10px;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label img:hover {
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label img {
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label img:hover {
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/i7379jf.png) no-repeat right bottom;
    background-size: 50px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:hover:after {


}
```

Comment: saw fiddle and thanks. So it will work for radio too. I will try and see if it works on mine.

Comment: OK attempted your example, but the problem is the border radius overlapping each other. Image would be background image inside label in order to have border radius as circle when hovered. then when checked, tick will appear with smaller border radius. Managed to get them working but only the problem is that when hovered, the smaller border will jump up and down.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Can you make changes to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cn7SC/4/) (insert your images and layout). I have given it a hover border radius.

Comment: your fiddle is correct according to what I wanted, but as you can see, the tick is jumpy every time the circle is hovered.

Comment: thanks but tick is missing. so there is no way for the tick to stay still when the big circle is hovered?

Comment: ah i saw. sorry about it. but is it possible for the image to be background image and still hovered with tick? I try your fiddle and see

Comment: Why do you want it to be a background image?

Comment: there will have one background image and one border-radius 10px solid red (border-radius: 100%) being hovered on image background. Also there will be one background image of tick with background color and border-radius - it appears after checked. so both border-radius overlap each other when hovered which is not right

Comment: thanks a lot for your help with example, I somehow managed to get mine working.